# How to delete a set of lines using awk when certain condition is met

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am using `awk` to delete duplicates in files, the problem is that I want to delete a set of lines if a duplicate is found, for eg-

```
<p>
This is duplicate.
</p>
<p>
This is original.
</p>
<p>
This is duplicate.
</p>
```

I would like to change it to-

```
<p>
This is duplicate.
</p>
<p>
This is original.
</p>
```

When a line is duplicated, delete both the previous and the next line, any help will be appreciated.

I am currently using-

```
awk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' name_of_file
```

to remove the duplicate line, but I am unable to figure out how to remove the previous as well as the next line.

Comment: What about `<p>This is duplicate</p>` without newline?

Comment: I do not have control over the format(format in which I receive it) of input file.

Comment: I'm just asking if you would also would want to delete that line. Especially if you have no control of the format.

Comment: Only duplicate has to be deleted, one entry can stay.

Comment: I understand that, but that was not my question ... will a second `<p>This is duplicate</p>` also need to be deleted if it has no newline (is the same tag but in a different format, which is totally valid for xml/html)....

Comment: No, that won't be deleted, the input won't be in that format, there are new lines after <p> tag (for sure)

Comment: I thought you had no control over the format, how can you be sure? Won't you want to use a proper xml/html parser instead of `awk` which will fail with a slight change of input.

Comment: The file is actually an xml file, it is already present in codebase, I just have to make a script that deletes duplicates, the script to add entries to the file is already sorted out. I have no control over input but the input format is well defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135370/discussion-between-thunderknight-and-plumo).

Comment: How to identify which lines you want to check for duplicates? The lines with `<p>` and `</p>` are also duplicates, but you don't want to have them checked. Should only lines without tags be checked for duplications?

Comment: @Philippos I skip the lines starting with <p> or </p>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're really trying to do is delete duplicate `<p>...</p>`-delimited records rather than individual lines. Given your posted example, that'd be this with GNU awk (which you're already using for `-i inplace)` for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="</p>\n"} !seen[$0]++' file
<p>
This is duplicate.
</p>
<p>
This is original.
</p>
```

Note that this works no matter how many lines are in the `<p>...</p>` record, e.g. given this input where the duplicate record is multiple lines:

```
$ cat file
<p>
This
is
duplicate.
</p>
<p>
This is original.
</p>
<p>
This
is
duplicate.
</p>
```

the script still removes the duplicate:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="</p>\n"} !seen[$0]++' file
<p>
This
is
duplicate.
</p>
<p>
This is original.
</p>
```

Comment: Oh yes, that's even simpler

Comment: Feel free to accept it if you're going to use it - https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: +1: In this case `RT` is really `RS` with no new line in `gawk`...? Not sure I read the manual well in that case.  ''' Gawk sets RT to the input text that matched the character or regular  expression specified by RS. '''

Comment: @Cbhihe `RT` is simply the string that matched `RS`, if any, there's no "with no new line" involved. In this case `RS` is `</p>\n` and so `RT` will always also be `</p>\n`. I had included a test for RT in the script before adding `\n` to `RS` to handle the `\n` that would then be left at the end of the file, which would not match RS of `</p>` but would have caused `ORS` of `</p>` to be printed, but forgot to remove it after changing RS to include the `\n`. I've updated my answer now. I may have made my explanation sound more complicated than it is - sorry, feel free to ask a followup question!

Comment: No, actually yr explanation makes perfect sense.  All good. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is not the right tool for parsing `xml`/`html` data, it will fail with a slight change of input format.

Better use some specified parser, e.g. `BeautifulSoup` from `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file.html') as f:
    content = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

p_contents=[]
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    p_content = p.get_text().strip()
    
    if p_content in p_contents:
        p.extract()
    else:
        p_contents.append(p_content)

print(soup)
```

Using `awk`:

```bsh
awk -v start="<p>" -v end="</p>" '
    $0 == start { tag=$0; in_tag=1 }
    !in_tag
    in_tag && ( $0 != start && $0 != end ) { tag=tag"\n"$0 }
    $0 == end { if (!seen[tag]++) { print tag"\n"$0 }; in_tag=0 }
' file.html
```

Comment: Though you are right that awk is not the right tool, I cannot use anything other than awk over here, it a condition that I can't avoid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The truth is: I don't know how to do such a thing in `awk`. With `sed` you could do

```
sed 'N;/\n</{P;D;};G;/\(\n[^<]*\n\).*\1/{N;d;};s/\n\n.*//;s/\n$//;H' file
```

The idea is to use an `N;P;D` cycle to always process two lines together. If the second one is not a tag line, test for duplication with lines kept in the hold space. `d`elete duplicates and append new originals to the `H`old space for future reference.

Please test without `-i` option first, so you don't mess your file. If it works and an `sed` solutionis okay for you, I'll add a more detailed  explanation.

Comment: Thanks for doing it with sed, really appreciate it.